# Pyinstaller on Flask app, import error

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller, flash-message

I have a Flask app comprising several modules, structured as follows:

```
.pears.py
├── app
│   ├── api
│   ├── indexer
│   ├── pod_finder
│   ├── search
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
│       ├── indexer
│       ├── pod_finder
│       └── search
```

pears.py starts the application with:

```
from app import app
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I've been writing this app in a virtualenv, so all necessary packages are in the env/ directory.

I have been trying to bundle this app with pyinstaller. The dist folder gets created without error messages, but when I try to run the executable, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pears.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
ImportError: No module named 'app'
[12110] Failed to execute script pears
```

I.e. the main module is not found. I am trying to understand why that is. Is the **init**.py file in app somehow not registered by pyinstaller? Do I need to do anything specific to make it visible? My spec file is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

added_files = [
     ( 'app/templates', 'templates' )
    ]

a = Analysis(['pears.spec'],
         pathex=['./env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/', './'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=added_files,
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='pears',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=True )

coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=False,
           upx=True,
           name='pears')
```

Comment: Try adding the full path of your app module directly to the pyinstaller when you build. Something like pyinstaller --paths <full_path_to_app> -F pears.py

Comment: Thanks. So now, I get what might be an unrelated error: 21609 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   urllib3.packages.six.moves
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six'. I tried to upgrade my urllib3 package but it's up-to-date.

Comment: Suggest making another question for that. Looks like a dependency issue to me. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775276/pyinstaller-error-importerror-no-module-named-requests-packages-chardet-sys